# How to interpret an ACF plot of residuals time series?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I have a daily time series starting (01/11/2022) and ending (30/06/2022).

I'm trying to make a model of my time series.

First, I made:

```
tsdata<- ts(gain_day_cut$`Gain per day`, start = 1, end = 171, frequency = 7)
tsdata_decompose <- decompose(tsdata)
residuals <- checkresiduals(remainder(tsdata_decompose))
tsdata_recompose <- tsdata_decompose$trend + tsdata_decompose$seasonal + tsdata_decompose$random
tsdata_error <- tsdata_recompose - tsdata
```

Using the checkresiduals() functions i get [image]

How can I interpret the ACF plot?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I would guess that you want to create deseasonalized residuals of your time series, but judging by your residual plot, they are still very seasonal

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely still a seasonality pattern in your residuals. You could plot the periodogram of your residuals to identify the frequency(ies) and remove the seasonality component. In order to fit a model, your residuals should be stationary (no trend, no seasonality). Then, you can start to plot the ACF, PACF, etc in order to find the right model.